# Syntax of the functor definition in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have an example functor deceleration as;

```
#include <iostream>

class myFunctorClass
{
    public:
        myFunctorClass (int x) : _x( x ) {}
        int operator() (int y) { return _x + y; }
    private:
        int _x;
};

int main()
{
    myFunctorClass addFive( 5 );
    std::cout << addFive( 6 );

    return 0;
}
```

My "What" is about the line just after the **public:**. I do not understand the syntax of the line `myFunctorClass (int x) : _x( x ) {}`. What is doing and what another instance of the use of such syntax rule?

Comment: It's a constructor, get [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Comment: And the functor is not slowing down, so "functor decelaration" is not a very meaningful term

Comment: It initializes the private member _x to the value specified when calling the constructor. So _x is initialized to 5 or 6 in your case even before the constructor actually runs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFunctorClass (int x) : _x( x ) {}` is the constructor. It's a function that is executed whenever an object of the class is instantiated.

The `: _x(x)` part is an initialization list. That means it initializes a member with a value (in this case the value `x` is used to initialize `_x`), or intializes a parent class.

The code would in this case be functionally equal to

```
myFunctorClass (int x) {
    _x = x; 
}
```

Note this equivalence is not always true. There are slight differences between initialization and assignment and copy/move-construction.

Comment: is it just for constructor or might be used for other function definitions.

Comment: @Erogol the initializer list is only for constructors. It would make no sense anywhere else.

Comment: Intialization lists can only be used in constructors. As the name implies, it's just there to _initialize_ the members or parents for the first time. This is especially useful for `const` members, as they can not be re-assigned, or parent classes that take constructor parameters themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the definition of `myFunctorClass`'s constructor. Perhaps it is just the `: _x( x )` part that is confusing you. Would `myFunctorClass (int x) {}` make sense to you? The `: _x( x )` part is a member initialization list and says that the member `_x` should be initialised with the value of the argument `x`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the class' constructor.  It's initializing the data members (after the :).  And the function body of the constructor us empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the class constructor member initializer list to initialize your member `_x` to `x` that was passed as `5` to the constructor in `myFunctorClass addFive( 5 );`